# Sonata Seo Bundle with MongoDB giving database connectivity error in sitemap with Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony-3.4, sonata

I am trying to connect Sonata Seo Bundle with MongoDB in Symfony 3.4 and try to generate sitemap through it.

But I am getting error as follows:

```
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Sonata\Exporter\Source\DoctrineDBALConnectionSourceIterator::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\  
  Driver\Connection, instance of MongoDB\Client given, called in var/cache/dev/ContainerXocz3o4/getSonata_Seo_Source_Do  
  ctrineSitemapIterator0Service.php on line 8
```

Sotana Seo Configuration is as follows:

```
sonata_seo:
    sitemap:
        doctrine_orm:
            - group: "news"
              connection: doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection
              route: home
              parameters: {}
              query: db.some_collection.find( {} ).limit(2)
```

Any help is much appreciated.